# How to set telugu font in textview?

Tags: java, android, fonts

I have following code to set the font for setting the telugu font. while checking from the json, the data is correct. but while checking in textview, there is the spelling mistake in the fonts.

`Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/vemana2000.ttf");
   holder.text.setTypeface(font);
   holder.text.setText(data[position]);`

How to solve this? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your font does not contain appropriate characters.

Comment: thats it. i require a font that supports the characters. i'm struggling for pas two days.